# Trendline AmCharts not work without date based

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Hello i use Trend Line in AmCharts, when i change value without date based it won't display vice versa.

Here is my code :

```
function drawGraph(amYear) {
            var trendLinesData = trendLines(chartData);

            // AmCharts.ready(function () {
            // SERIAL CHART
            chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();

            chart.dataProvider = chartData;
            chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM";
            chart.categoryField = "field";
            chart.startDuration = 2;

            // AXES
            // category
            var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
            categoryAxis.parseDates = false; // as our data is date-based, we set parseDates to true
            categoryAxis.minPeriod = "MM"; // our data is daily, so we set minPeriod to DD
            categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
            categoryAxis.minorGridAlpha = 0.1;
            categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
            categoryAxis.minorGridEnabled = true;
            categoryAxis.inside = true;

            // value
            var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
            valueAxis.title = "Total";
            valueAxis.tickLength = 0;
            valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
            valueAxis.showFirstLabel = false;
            valueAxis.showLastLabel = false;
            chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

            // GRAPH
            var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.dashLength = 5;
            graph.lineColor = "#3498db";
            graph.valueField = "value";
            graph.lineThickness = 1;
            chart.addGraph(graph);

            // SCROLLBAR
            var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
            chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

            // TREND LINES
            // first trend line
            var trendLine = new AmCharts.TrendLine();
            trendLine.initialValue =  5;
            trendLine.initialXValue =  5;
            trendLine.finalValue =  30;
            trendLine.finalXValue =  40;
            trendLine.lineColor = "#000";

            chart.addTrendLine(trendLine);

            // WRITE
            chart.write("datachart");
        // });
        }
```

I already try another property and i call chart.validateNow() but it still not work.
How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

In a non-date-based Serial chart (which according to the code you posted you seem to be using) you need to use [`initialCategory`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/TrendLine#initialCategory) and [`finalCategory`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/TrendLine#finalCategory).

They need to contain strings exactly as you have them in data category field (`field` in your case).

The `initialXValue` and `finalXValue` are relevant for XY chart only.